# Windows 10 causing error on booting Tails from USB

Tags: tails, windows

I get an error that says "WARNING: No configuration file found" and my screen turns bright red and doesn't do anything. I disabled "Safe Boot" the Bios option, and it won't boot via USB. I am using Windows 10 and was wondering perhaps that may be the cause.

Comment: Does the Windows 10 machine run on an x86 architecture or ARM? If your processor is an ARM architecture, then you will not be able to boot tails.

Comment: When you were installing tails using the installation guide at https://tails.boum.org there should have been a step where you were told to boot the USB and that if you had any problems it presented you with a set of troubleshooting steps to go through, can you tell us the outcome of those steps?

Comment: I tried the troubleshooting steps and disabled secure boot, i had boot by usb on the top priority, i didnt see an option for fast boot or legacy mode. My processor is not ARM architecture. And now whenever i boot up my computer is starts on that big red screen and looks like an error, but it flashes back to the regular boot screen and everything is fine... Its just strange how when i turn it on it starts bright red now. Dont know what happened there.

Comment: I think the error you're seeing is related to UEFI boot, CSM or Legacy boot might fix it. It might be worth checking the device vendors manual to see if theres information available for either of those terms. http://www.chronicles.no/2016/04/tail-linux-on-surface-pro-one.html seems to be someone who had similar problems, possibly related to universal usb installer? would it be possible to try one of the other methods, e.g. install from ubuntu or debian?

Comment: Ok so install from ubuntu or debian? I am on windows so I just instll debian? I'm not sure how to install debian, it's a bit confusing. I will try the solution suggested on reddit that you mentioned though and get backk  to you

Comment: Alright! It worked by installing the inital tails through rufus.... But my mouse and keyboard don't work in the Tails OS. I think the device isn't perfectly compatible? So the Surface pro 3 doesn't have a physical keyboard and isw a touchscreen. I have a keyboard attackment and a mouse via usb. I unplugged the mouse though so I could plug in the tails usb. So how would I get the keyboard attachment to work? I'd assume Tails needs the drivers..?

Comment: I had the same problem -- here's what I did:
-- disable secure boot
-- enable CSM
-- move your USB device to the tob of boot options
Hope this helps.

Comment: I haven't found an option to enable CSM on Windows 10... Does anyone know where that is?